# Unexpected label above wire element

Tags: labels, circuitikz

What went wrong here? How can I get rid of the label Rs hovering above the wire?

```
\begin{figure}[h!]
\begin{center}
    \begin{circuitikz}
        \draw (-0.5,0) to [short, o-] (0,0);
        \draw (0,0) [R, l=$R_s$] to (2,0) [L, l=L] to (4,0);
        \draw (4,0) to [short, -o] (4.5,0);
        \draw (0,0)--(0,-1) [C, l_=$C_d$] to (4,-1)--(4,0);
    \end{circuitikz}
    \caption[]{Equivalent circuit of a inductor.}
    \label{}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
\FloatBarrier
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably you looking for something like this:

[image]

You have a mismatch in your code. Correct is (observe position of `to`):

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{circuitikz}
\draw  (-0.5,0) to [short, o-] (0,0)
                to [R, l=$R_s$] (2,0) 
                to [L, l=L] (4,0)
                to [short, -o] (4.5,0)
       (0,0)--(0,-1) to [C, l_=$C_d$] (4,-1)--(4,0);
    \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```